# R periodic function call inside docker container

Tags: r, docker

As described by https://yihui.org/en/2017/10/later-recursion/, It is possible to instruct R to execute a function periodically with a timed delay using the `later::later` package

As a minimal example, consider following `main.R` and `Dockerfile`:

```
# main.R:
timer <- function() {
  print("repeat after 3 seconds")
  later::later(timer, 3)
}
timer()
```

```
# Dockerfile
FROM rocker/r-base:4.1.2

RUN R -e "install.packages('later')"

COPY / /

ENTRYPOINT ["Rscript", "main.R"]
```

build with `docker build -t r-timer` and running the container with `docker run r-timer` makes the loop execute exactly once, after which the container exits. terminal output:

```
$ docker run r-timer
[1] "repeat after 3 seconds"


$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE    COMMAND          CREATED             STATUS
aa1c33b39c2e   r-timer  "Rscript main.R" About a minute ago  Exited (0) About a minute ago
```

my questions:

- Does using later::later mean the thread is suspended, which makes docker believe there is no running process and the container is thus stopped?
- How can I keep the container running and make R run continuously?

### EDIT:

Thanks to @danlooo I learned about docker killing any background tasks when the container finishes the main thread. I adapted the Dockerfile to do a UNIX sleep on the main thread, pushing the Rscript thread to the background. To monitor the behaviour I added log4r to print lines to a file rather than using print(). I'm still seeing the same behaviour: when accessing the container and checking info.log, it only contains an entry for ONE execution.

```
library("log4r")
log_file <- "info.log"
log <- logger("INFO", appenders = file_appender(log_file))
info(log,"started logger")
timer <- function() {
  info(log, "Repeat after 3 seconds")
  later::later(timer, 3)
}
timer()
```

```
FROM rocker/r-base:4.1.2

RUN R -e "install.packages('later')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('log4r')"

COPY / /

CMD Rscript main.R & tail -f info.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Docker container automatically shut down once the init process finished. If `later` is spinning up a background process, it will be killed when `main.R` just finished. You can use `CMD Rscript main.R && wait` in your Dockerfile to wait for all background processes. Another approach is to prevent the container from stopping at all using `CMD exec /bin/bash -c "trap : TERM INT; Rscript main.R; sleep infinity & wait"`

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. The first option (`CMD Rscript main.R`) still exits my  container after just 1 loop, the second one doesn't exit, but "repeat after 3 seconds" is only printed once. I suppose the call is still happening, but since it's executed in a background thread, the output isn't directed to stdout?

Comment: btw: `later` will always execute a function only once but later. Use `lapply(seq(3), function(x) {Sys.sleep(1); message("hi")})` instead to print a message 3 times in a row with 1s in between.

Comment: gotcha on the later executes once part. However, I've been testing further, using Log4r to write logs to a file instead of relying on stdout. (I edited my original question with the details)

Comment: I'm not into `Log4r`. This seems to be a new question

Comment: well, my question isn't really about log4r, but about the recursive function call that's only getting executed once. log4r was just a way for me to check whether the background task is still running if I keep a UNIX  sleep on the foreground task.

Still, thanks for your time, I learned a thing or two I didn't consider before :)